# Analog phase shifting circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, ultrasound, phase-shift

I have a high voltage(let's say +-100Vpp) sine signal of 500khz and i want this signal to be phase shifted(+ve) by 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees.
That is a circuit which has 500khz input signal and 4 outputs with 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees phase shifted.
I do not want any attenuation in the circuit. I have looked into op-amp/transistor circuits with RC Components. But have not come very far with that yet.
Sugestions?

Comment: Either the 9 questions you've asked have been poorly received and not attracted answers that you can formally accept or you didn't know about formally accepting the best answer to your questions. I expect some of your 9 questions can be closed down now by formal answer acceptance.

Comment: Invert (using a transformer) for a simple way of generating the complements. Then you only need a 90 degree phase shift.

Comment: You can use Balun followed by polyphase filter to generate all the phases.

Comment: Maybe a really long wire? About 500 feet?